# Phantom colon appearing in Tumblr Theme

Tags: html, css

I'm having a first crack at a custom Tumblr theme and I've begun to encounter a phantom colon. I've traced its origin to the overlay div but I can't delete it as the caption is served from Tumblr.

This is the code in question:

```
<div class="leftcolumn">

       <div class="item"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}"> 

       <div class="overlay"> {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}</div>  </div>

       </div>
```

and if you squint you can make out the offending colon beneath the bottom left corner of the image (in the orange):

[colon on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw42F.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should post a link to your blog. Although there is an answer, using js to remove the element might be heavy, it could just be a small css issue, or something in template. What if there was meant to be a colon in the text?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using css, you could try:

```
.leftcolumn .overlay {
   text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Using jQuery:

```
var withColonsRemoved = $('.leftcolumn .overlay').text().replace(/\:/g, '');;
$('.leftcolumn .overlay').text( withColonsRemoved );
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4dt6gxg/)

Comment: Thanks, but that only moves the colon (along with the tumblr caption which I'd like to keep), I'm trying to delete the colon without losing the caption if possible

Comment: Bingo - Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3649848 Welcome!

Comment: @user3649848 Could I ask you mark this as correct. Thank you.

Comment: This is like using a meat axe to make a surgical incision.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making the text *invisible*:

```
.leftcolumn .overlay {
   color: transparent;
}
```

Or you could even make the text *shrink*:

```
.leftcolumn .overlay {
   font-size: 0
}
```